# Using Spring Auth Server for server to server authentication (x.509 signed JWT assertion)

Tags: spring-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I've been trying to configure the Spring Authentication Server (v.1.1.2) for backend to backend authentication. An access token would be requested by sending a POST request to the token endpoint like that:

```
POST /token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=urn%3Ayour-broker%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Apersonal-jwt
&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjE2In0.eyJpc3Mi...
&client_id=1234-5678-9101
&client_secret=abcdefghijklmn
```

`assertion` contains a JWT created and signed with a X.509 certificate of the server. The certificate is provided to the remote party along with the `client_id` and `client_secret` params in advance.

This kind of getting an access token refers to [JWT Bearer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7523#section-2.1) grant type.

Unfortunately I've been unable to configure the Spring Authentication Server to process such authentication request.

Any guidance, code snippets would be of great help!